# Using Python to manipulate csv files: vlookup from another csv, insert columns, delete rows, loop

Tags: python, csv, pandas, match

I have 100 csv files, each contains publication data of different institutions and I would like to perform the same manipulation on all of them:

1.Get the Institution name from cell B1. This is always after 'at' or 'at the'. For example 'Publications at Tohoku University'
2.Vlookup the matching InstitutionCode from another csv file called 'Codes'.
For example '1286'. (for Tohoku University).
3.Delete rows 1-14 (including the Insitution name in cell B1)
4. Insert two extra columns (column A and B) to the file with he following headers: 'Institution' and 'InstitutionCode' and fill it with the relevant information for all rows where I have data.
(In the above example Tohoku University and 1286).

I am new to Python and find it hard to put together this script from the resources I have found.
Can anyone please help me?

Below is  image of the data in original format

[image: Data in original format]

Below is the image of the result required

[image: Result required]

Comment: For starters you should look at using the python data analysis library called Pandas. [Here is a link to the tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/tutorials.html)

Answer (score 4):

I could give you the code, but instead, I'll explain to you how you can write it yourself.

1. Read the Codes file and store the institutions and codes in a dictionary.
   You can read more about reading csv files here: https://pymotw.com/2/csv/ or here: https://pymotw.com/3/csv/.
   Each row will be represented as a list of strings, so you can access cell elements by their index. Make the Institution names the keys and the codes the values.
2. Read the csv files one by one in a for loop. I'll call these the input files. Open a new file for writing for each input file that you read. I'll call these the output files.
3. Loop over the rows in the csv file. You can keep track of the row numbers by using enumerate. You can find info on this here for example: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html.
4. Get the contents of cell B1 by taking element 1 from row 0.
5. Find the Institution name by using a regular expression. More info here for example: http://dev.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm
   And get the Institution code from the dictionary you made in step 1.
6. Keep looping over the rows, until the first element equals 'Title'. This row contains the headers. Write "Institution" and "InstitutionCode" to the output file, followed by the headers you just found. To do this, convert your row (a list of strings) to a tuple (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) and give that as an argument to the writerow method of the csv writer object (see the links in step 1).
7. Then for each row after the header row, make a tuple of the Institution name and code, followed by the information from the row from the input file you just read, and give that as an argument to the writerow method of the csv writer object.
8. Close output file.

One thing to think about is whether you want quotes around the cell contents in the output files. You can read about this in the links in step 1. The same goes for the field delimiters. If you don't specify anything, they are assumed to be commas, but you can change this.

I hope this helps!